# Python Tkinter GUI display numpy array in a numbered single row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to use Python with Tkinter. I would like to have a numpy array shown in the GUI as one long row with their position number but I'm struggling to figure out how to do so. This is my function for this operation

```
     def windspeed():                     

        minSpeed2 = float(minSpeed_entry.get()) # Get value from entry box and converts to float float
        maxSpeed2 = float(maxSpeed_entry.get()) 

        if minSpeed2 >= maxSpeed2:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Speed error", "your minimum speed cannot be greater or equal to the max speed") # gives error if max speed is lower than min speed

        windspeed2 = wind_speed(minSpeed2,maxSpeed2)
        windspeed2 = np.round(windspeed2,3)


        shortwindspeed2 = windspeed2[0:10]

        speedbox.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        speedbox.insert(tk.END, shortwindspeed2) # this is where i think the problem is
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

However I would like it to look like this:

[image]

But with the position in the array next to it.

For example:

```
index 0: 3.8
index 1: 3.9
index 2: 4.0
index 3: 4.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a numpy array displayed as text and including the indices.

The following code should solve your problem:

```py
windspeed2 = np.array([3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1]) # this is just for testing. don't copy this line :)

windspeed2_head = windspeed2[:10] # take the first 10 elements
windspeed2_readable = '\n'.join([f"index {i}: {w}" for i, w in enumerate(windspeed2_head)])

print(windspeed2_readable) 
#speedbox.insert(tk.END, windspeed2_readable)
```

To be easily reproducable, I added a `print` statement where you would place `speedbox.insert(tk.END, windspeed2_readable)`.

So, what are we doing here? With the `enumerate` statement we can add indices to any iterable. See this example:

```
 >>> print(list(enumerate("hello")))
  [(0, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

To get `windspeed2_readable` we are iterating over the enumerated values in `windspeed2_head`. We are assigning the current index to `i` and the corresponding wind speed to `w`. Now we are converting these two variables to a string by using a f-string: `f"index {i}: {w}"`.

In the end, this part

```
 >>> [f"index {i}: {w}" for i, w in enumerate(windspeed2_head)]
 ['index 0: 3.8', 'index 1: 3.9', 'index 2: 4.0', 'index 3: 4.1']
```

provides us with a list of strings. Now we just have to join them with a newline character `'\n'` as the separator.

Comment: Works flawlessly thanks a lot :D https://i.imgur.com/2amTB66.png